# SSRS - Getting this error: Numeric aggregate function on data that is not numeric

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have a report that is giving me grief about this statement:

```
Format((Sum(Fields!Mean.Value)) / RowNumber("category_desc"), "F2")
```

The mean field is a calculated field that is the sum of five fields in my table.  Category_desc is the group.

When I run the report, I get #Error in the textbox and this error in the log:

```
‘Textbox119.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses a numeric aggregate function on data that is not numeric.  Numeric aggregate functions (Sum, Avg, StDev, Var, StDevP, and VarP) can only aggregate numeric data.
```

I don't know why this error is occurring or how I can stop it.  Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure your calculated field is returning a numeric type - explicitly cast the return value within your expression.

You can also try to eliminate any potential non-numerics coming into your SUM, as it sounds like "Mean" might contain text data:

```
Sum(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Mean.Value), CDbl(Fields!Mean.Value), 0))
```